# XAML only Multibinding / Trigger in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have read-only access to a view-model, connected to my XAML view.

In Pseudo-ish code, it looks something like:

```
public class HelloWorld:INotifyPropertyChanged{
  private int _counter;
  public int Counter {get{return ++_counter;}}
  public bool Foo {get{...}set{...InvokeINotifyPropertyChanged("Foo");}}
}
```

I have a `TextBlock` with it's `Text` property bound to `Counter`, but would like it's value to be re-evaluated when `Foo` is changed / set, in markup only.

I can solve this problem, by binding `TextBlock`'s `Text` property to a `MultiBinding` and including both `Counter` and `Foo` as bindings, followed by creating a Converter that implements `IMultiValueConverter`, but this seems a bit like overkill.

Is there a nicer way?

Comment: If you have access to an instance of `HelloWorld` you could subscribe to `PropertyChanged` event of `HelloWorld` and in the event if property name is null, empty or `Foo` raise the event for `Counter`

Comment: Good thinking. I would still like to see if there is a XAML only-approach. Unfortunately it seems `DataTrigger` only works with hardcoded values.

Comment: I don't think there is XAML only solution

Comment: In this case I'd say that solving it in the view model will be much simpler than trying to come up with some XAML hack. Besides, increasing the counter in the getter seems a bit risky. For example, what if another control is bound to the Counter?

Answer (score 1):

When you say read-only, you mean that you can't even access the ViewModel source code? In this case, i would recommend something like this:

```
public TestClass()
{
    _viewModel.PropertyChanged += OnPropertyChanged;
}

private void OnPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.PropertyName == "Foo")
    {
        _textBlock.GetBindingExpression(TextBlock.TextProperty).UpdateTarget();
    }
}
```

But if you have access to the View-Model code, you can simply call InvokeINotifyPropertyChanged("Counter") on Foo setter.

Comment: Where are you getting the reference to `_textBlock` from?